# Proof by Smallest counterexample: for integers >= 5, $2^n$ > $n^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples

Can anyone explain how they went from

$2^x$ to $x^2$ from lines 12 to 13? This has to be a mistake in the textbook proof, right?

[image]

[image]

Comment: No. They want to show (13) because that will imply the result.

Comment: @ADA It doesn't look like it, since they never go back to (12) again after that. I have added the rest of the proof. If what you're saying is true, could you explain how they go from (12) to the end? I'm getting completely lost after (12).

Comment: Transitive property of inequality. If we want $x > z$ and know $x > y$, it is sufficient to prove $y > z$

Comment: @george they don’t need to.

Answer (score 1):

The words here are absolutely critical, and the logic of the proof is a little hard to follow. I will use the symbol $\Rightarrow$ to represent "implies" and $\Leftrightarrow$ to represent "if and only if"/"is equivalent to". Here is an explanation of the argument starting from $(12)$.

1. Tha assumption (in context) is that $\boxed{x\ge6}$.
2. The goal (in context) is to show that $2^x>x^2$ so that $x$ wasn't
   actually a counterexample.
3. They have shown (in context) equation $\boxed{(12)}$.
4. "We will be finished once we can prove [$(13)]$." is not a claim of $(13)$, it's a claim that $(13)$ and $(12)$ together would give the desired result: $\boxed{\left((12)\text{ and }(13)\right)\Rightarrow\text{goal}}$. This implication is true because of how inequalities work. $a>b\ge c\Rightarrow a>c$ in general, so $2^x>2x^2-4x+2\ge x^2\Rightarrow 2^x>x^2$.
5. "To prove Equation (18), we just need to prove [$(14)$]". I think "$(18)$" is a typo for "$(13)$" here. So this is saying $\boxed{(14)\Rightarrow(13)}$. Why? Well "We got $(14)$ from $(13)$ by adding $2-x^2$ to both sides", so that if we subtracted $2-x^2$ from both sides of $(14)$, we would get $(13)$.
6. "Notice that Equation $(14)$ can be rewritten [as $(15)$]." means that $\boxed{(14)\Leftrightarrow(15)}$.
7. "So we have reduced the problem to proving Equation $(15)$" means that $\boxed{(15)\Rightarrow\text{goal}}$ (in context). Why? Well $(15)\Rightarrow(14)\Rightarrow(13)$ (by my points 6. and 5.), and we have $(12)$ (my point 3.), and $\left((12)\text{ and }(13)\right)\Rightarrow\text{goal}$ (my point 4.).
8. "and to prove that, it certainly is enough to prove [$(16)$]." means $\boxed{(16)\Rightarrow(15)}$. Why? Squaring a number that's at least $1$ makes it bigger (or the same) and if we have $x-2\ge2$ then $x-2$ is a number that's at least $1$, so $(x-2)^2\ge(x-2)\ge2$ so $(x-2)^2\ge2$.
9. "and that's true because $x\ge6$ (all we need is $x\ge4$)." means $\boxed{x\ge6\Rightarrow x\ge4\Rightarrow (16)}$. Why? The first implication is because $6\ge4$ and the second is by subtracting $2$ from each side of $x\ge4$.
10. They didn't write this explicitly, but since we are assuming $x\ge6$ (my point 1.), we get $(16)$ (by my point 9.), so we get $(15)$ (by my point 8.), so we get the goal (by my point 7.).